# GtkOverlay: Prevent redraw of background widget?

Tags: gtk, gtk3

I want to overlay a GtkDrawingArea with a GtkSpinner to signify some calculations are going on. However, I've noted that when the spinner is active, the drawing area is redrawn very often, presumably at the rate of the spinning animation. Is there a way to prevent this redrawing, as the function is somewhat expensive.

The basic layout is a GtkOverlay with pass-through activated and a GtkDrawingArea as main child (index -1) and a GtkSpinner as a secondary child (index 0). I've tried some more combinations but to no avail.

Comment: I think this is a bug in GTK 3, but I have never been able to isolate it.

Comment: That would be unfortunate. Is this generally the case with every overlay combination or only with spinners?

Comment: Only with spinners that I've noticed, but it may happen with anything that's being animated by CSS.

Comment: As a workaround, can you make an early return in your drawing code, when the spinner is visible, or prevent redrawing unless a specific time has elapsed since last update?

Comment: I had thought about that as well, but I didn't want to prevent redrawing of the area entirely while the computation (on another thread) was going on. I suppose spinners might just not be a good choice for this and should be rather used like little icons in a tab for instance. I think I will go with a different mouse cursor instead.